# authors list page in WordPress doesn't work well

Tags: wordpress

I have an authors list in my blog to show people who write on the blog. However, there's this problem that FaceBook, Twitter and YouTube values for first author are the same for all authors

this is the code

```
<?php
/*Template Name: قائمة محررى الموقع*/
// Get all users order by amount of posts
$allUsers = get_users('orderby=post_count&order=DESC');
$users = array();
// Remove subscribers from the list as they won't write any articles
foreach($allUsers as $currentUser)
{
if(!in_array( 'subscriber', $currentUser->roles ))
{
$users[] = $currentUser;
}
}
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
</div>
<section id="auther-list-temp" role="main">
<?php
foreach($users as $user)
{ ?>
<div class="author">
<div class="authorAvatar">
<?php echo get_avatar( $user->user_email, '128' ); ?>
</div>
<div class="authorInfo">
<h2 class="authorName"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></h2>
<p class="authorDescrption"><?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'description', true); ?></p>
<p class="authorLinks"><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $user->ID ); ?>">اعرض جميع مواضيع العضو</a></p>
<?php $website = $user->user_url;
if($user->user_url != ''){
printf('
<div class="site-name"><a href="%s">%s</a>
', $user->user_url, 'الموقع');
} ?></div>          
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('twitter', $author->post_author) || get_the_author_meta('facebook', $author->post_author) || get_the_author_meta('youtube', $author->post_author) || get_the_author_meta('digg', $author->post_author) || get_the_author_meta('flickr', $author->post_author)): ?>
<ul class='connect'><?php if(get_the_author_meta('twitter', $author->post_author)): ?>
<li class="twitter-name"><a href='http://twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta('twitter', $author->post_author); ?>'>twitter</a></li><?php endif; ?>
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('facebook', $author->post_author)): ?>
<li class="facebook-name"><a href='http://www.facebook.com/<?php the_author_meta('facebook', $author->post_author); ?>'>facebook</a></li><?php endif; ?>
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('youtube', $author->post_author)): ?>
<li class="youtube-name"><a href='http://www.youtube.com/<?php the_author_meta('youtube', $author->post_author); ?>'>youtube</a></li>
<?php endif; ?><?php endif; ?></ul>
</div></div>
<?php } ?>
</section>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does `$author` get initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're only showing the FaceBook, Twitter and YouTube values for the author of the current article.

Try replacing every occurrence of `$author->post_author` with `$user->ID`.